# How to use grep to search word with specific number of occurence

Tags: grep

How can I search a text in a file that matches such condition: starts with 'x' and and have at least 1 'a' immediately after the 'x' and at most 2 'a's immediately following the 'a'.

I tried something like

```
grep -i ^xa{1..2} textfile.txt
```

but I think I am not understanding the usage of it

Comment: so basically, you are looking for the pattern "xaaa" ?

Comment: You should add some examples of text input and an an example of the expected result. It looks like you don't want to match `xaaaax`. Please clearify by editing your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat ip.txt 
xe
xa
xaaaalt
xaaa
xaa

$ # match 'a' 1 to 3 times
$ grep -i '^xa\{1,3\}' ip.txt
xa
xaaaalt
xaaa
xaa

$ # with ERE, no need to escape {}
$ grep -iE '^xa{1,3}' ip.txt
xa
xaaaalt
xaaa
xaa
```

To prevent matching more than three consecutive `a` matching, you'd need

```
$ grep -iE '^xa{1,3}([^a]|$)' ip.txt
xa
xaaa
xaa

$ # or lookarounds with PCRE
$ grep -iP '^xa{1,3}(?!a)' ip.txt
xa
xaaa
xaa
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close:

```
grep -i -E '^xaa{0,2}' textfile.txt
```

The syntax `{n,m}` (with `,` and not `..`) is an extended regexp, hence the `-E` option. `{` and `}` need to be quoted so that the shell doesn't interpret them.

Answer (score 0):

Given the input

```
1       x
2       xa
3       xaa
4       xaaa
5       xaaaa
```

Lines 2, 3 and 4 will be returned by

```
grep -wE 'xa{1,3}'
```

The extended regular expression `xa{1,3}` will match any `x` followed by between 1 and 3 `a`.  The `-w` option to `grep` makes sure that the matching text in the input is a complete word (which is why line 5 is not returned).